# remove file extensions from a file directory in php

Tags: php, jquery, file-extension

I am doing a gallery and using php to get images to show up without hard-coding for each image. I had used the following method for obtaining the images:

```
<?php
$dir="image/";
//open dir
if ($opendir=opendir($dir))
{
    //readdir

    while($file=readdir($opendir))
    {
        if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
    echo "
    <div id='item' class='grid-item'>
    <a href='$dir/$file'>
    <div id='masks' class='mask'></div>
    <div id='title' class='text'>$file</div>
    <img src='$dir/$file'>
    </a>
</div>

";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

The gallery uses jquery for the masonry gallery plugin.

However the file extension is showing up along with the file name. I don't want the extension. I have tried many methods, but they're not working for this case. How can I hide it and what changes can be done to the code in order for it to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
<?php

$dir="image/";
//open dir
if ($opendir=opendir($dir))
{
    //readdir

    while($file=readdir($opendir))
    {
        if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
        {
            $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            echo "
    <div id='item' class='grid-item'>
    <a href='$dir/$file'>
    <div id='masks' class='mask'></div>
    <div id='title' class='text'>$filename</div>
    <img src='$dir/$file'>
    </a>
</div>

";
        }

    }
}
```

To get the filename via this method, you must use PHP > 5.2, which you probably should anyway.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!